# How to run a function before constructors from global variables

Tags: c++, gcc, constructor, attributes

I have a ncurses program in c++ with global variables, which one containing the WINDOW*.

The problem is that I don't want to init every routines from ncurses in this constructor. I do want to init my ncurses things before everything else.

Here is my constructor :

```
 37 Window_c::Window_c()
 38 {
 41     // Create the window and check for errors
 42     if ((m_Window = newwin(0, 0, 0, 0)) == NULL) {
 43     ┊   fprintf(stderr, "[ERROR] - Unable to open the Window\n");
 44     ┊   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 45     }
 46 }
```

and here is my supposed main :

```
 33 __attribute__((constructor)) void CursesBeginRoutine(void)   
 34 {    
 35     initscr();   
 36     cbreak();        
 37     noecho();            
 38     keypad(stdscr, TRUE);   
 39 }
 40 
 41 int main(int argc __attribute__((unused)), char const *const argv[] __attribute__((unu|
 42 {
 43     MainLoop();
 44     return 0;
 45 }
 46                                                                                        
 47 __attribute__((destructor)) void CursesEndRoutine(void)
 48 {
 49     endwin();
 50 }
```

Sadly, it isn't working since gcc's attributes are called after constructors which is logic.

How can I do those things ?

Comment: don't use a global and create your window in main?

Comment: @UKMonkey ofc this is a pertinent answer but I don't want to send to every functions my class

Comment: Use a global and create your window in main?

Comment: Then don't call newwin in the constructor. Or don't make the object itself a global variable. You could create the object in main and have a global pointer variable that points to it. Or std::optional.

Comment: @user253751 indeed but this is quite illogical since this is why constructors exist

Comment: Okay i'll check that thanks

Comment: When does the window need to be constructed by? If we could bypass the whole globals-constructed-before-main thing, would there be a problem for your global?

Comment: Move `CursesBeginRoutine` before global `WINDOW` (and possibly make it also a global as order of constructor of global inside a TU is defined).

Comment: @JaMiT The window needs to be custructed before the other constructors are called (which are called by another global constructor) and after ncurses routines.
But, indeedn globals do not need to be inited before main

Answer (score 0):

Okay so... it was just my bad since my constructor attributes weren't in the same file.
Cause of that, they were calling before, probably because of my compilation/linkage order ? honnestly I don't really know why but, attributes are indeed called before constructors of global variables

sorry for everything and thank you

Comment: Order in which files (and therefore global/static variables) are processed is unspecified. This problem is called "static initialization fiasco".

Comment: @Yksisarvinen then, it was really badly done by myself, because it could have worked

Answer (score 0):

One way to delay initialization is to wrap your variable in a function. The idea is that the initialization will not occur until the function is called, yet the function can still exist at global scope.

There might be some intricacies to work out with your globals if there are interdependencies. The question does not contain all the details (and probably shouldn't), but applying the principle to a single global might be enough to get you started. Let's assume your global is called `Window`. Instead of accessing `Window` directly, your code would call a function that we'll call `GetWindow()` for now. (Use whatever naming scheme fits your style.)

```
Window_c & GetWindow()
{
    static Window_c Window;
    return Window;
}
```

The idea is that `Window` will not be constructed until this function is called. That gives you time to finish other initializations first. Just be aware that there could be problems if your *destructor* order becomes relevant. A lot could be (and has been) written on the subject. The key search phrase for further reading is "static initialization order fiasco". One reference is [ISO C++](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order).

There is some run-time overhead with this approach. Worrying about that overhead from the start is probably premature, but it could be useful to know that the overhead does exist. (Basically, every time the function is called, the program has to check a boolean flag to determine if the variable has been initialized.)

Comment: This is indeed a really good idea, but it seems honnestly really hard to apply.

Comment: @DiantArts The difficulty depends on your situation. I find that having options is nice. ;) Putting all of your timing-critical code into one source file is also a reasonable option, as long as that file does not become too cluttered.